# Add an item to first li in list of elements via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of `<li>`,which i am doing foreach, list of items are displaying search suggestions. I want to add additonal `<li>` only to first `<li>` indicating "search results for keyword " . Following is my code,

```
nksXhr = jQuery.post( nks.ajaxUrl, data, function( response ) {
        var lists = response.data;
        var str  = '';
        var word = $('.find-post').val();
        // console.log(lists);
        // <li class="ui-autocomplete-heading">Search results for <span>' + word + '</span></li>
        var searchResultsFor = '<li class="nks"> search results for:'+ word+'</li>';
        lists.forEach( function( list ) {
            str += '<li class="nks-redirect" data-href="' + list.link + '"><span class="ac-text"><h6>' + list.title + '</h6></span></li>';
        });
        if ( lists.length === 0 ) {
            str += '<li class="nks-no-results">No results for ' + word  +'</li>';
        }
        else {
            searchResultsFor += str;
        }
        searchInput.parent().find( '.nks-suggestions' ).addClass( 'nks-open-suggestions' );
        searchInput.parent().find( '.nks-suggestions' ).html( str );
        searchInput.parent().find( '.nks-loader' ).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use `searchResultsFor` to insert into the document

Try changing :

```
else {
    searchResultsFor += str;
}
```

To

```
else {
    str = searchResultsFor + str;
}
```

Then when you do `.html( str )` it will be included

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nks-suggestions").prepend('<li class="nks"> search results for keyword</li>');
```